# Is it possible to migrate Polymer 3 Components to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, migration, polymer, components

I have been using Polymer to build a large CMS. Unfortunately Polymer is slowly being phased out and I want to move to React step by step. Therefore I want to migrate Polymer-Components to my React App.

To summarize:
Is there any way to import and use my Polymer-Components inside of React?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Polymer inside of React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365545/is-it-possible-to-use-polymer-inside-of-react)

Comment: Thank you very much jmargolisvt. Unfortunately that question is concering Polymer 2, that's why I asked here.

Comment: From what I understood the development for Polymer stopped because the native support in browsers became pretty decent and this was always the point of Polymer: to bring web componenets to the browsers. If you want to keep the app based on web components you can migrate for LitElement, for example. If you really want React I guess you could import the elements in a react app and use them as regular tags.